# Push Notification - Do we need to update p12 on server for new certificate?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Application live on App Store from last 2 years. My problem is as below:

Now i have made changes in application and to upload new version of that application on app store. I have generated new certificate from apple account as the old one is expired and provisioning profile. Now if i submit new version to app store, shall push notification work?

I am testing in Ad Hoc version, but its not working. If it not works then i have to update p12 after new version of application goes live. Then push notification will not work for those users who don't take update of new version.

Can you please suggest your approach for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

The certificate is not packaged into your app. It's only required by your server in order to send push notifications.
Therefore you should only update the p12 file on your server. It will work for both users who use the new version and users who use the old version of your app.

If you don't update the certificate on your server, you won't be able to send push notifications to any version of your app, since, as you said, the old certificate has expired.

Comment: Old certificate has expired, so far push notification is working as its in production mode.